# Pundit raising AuthorizationNotPerformedError on a loop where authorize object is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I have two rails app : 
one is a "front-end app" responsible for displaying data, taking input from the user and sending data to the API (the second app). The second is an API dealing with database operations and sending JSON to the front end app.

I have an action where my user decides how many `rooms`he wants to create in his `hotel` and how many `beds`should he create in each `room`. The form on the front end app looks like that :

```
<h1>Add Rooms</h1>
<form action="http://localhost:3000/hotels/<%=params[:hotel_id]%>/rooms/multiple_create" method="post">
  <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag 'room[room_number]', "Number of rooms" %>
    <input type="number" name="room[room_number]" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "room[bed_number]", "Number of beds by room" %>
    <input type="number" name= "room[bed_number]" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "room[content]", "Room Type" %>
    <input type="text" name= "room[content]" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
    <% if @errors %>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <%@errors.each do |error|%>
        <li class="has-error"><%=error%></li>
      <% end -%>
    </ul>
  <% end -%>
</form>
```

This form is linked to my RoomsController#multiple_create action on the front-end app that is responsible for sending the form data to the API :

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def multiple_new
  end

  def multiple_create
    @response =   HTTParty.post(ENV['API_ADDRESS']+'api/v1/hotels/'+ params[:hotel_id]+'/rooms/multiple_create',
    :body => { :room =>{
                  :room_number => params[:room][:room_number],
                  :bed_number => params[:room][:bed_number],
                }
             }.to_json,
    :headers => { 'X-User-Email' => session[:user_email], 'X-User-Token'=> session[:user_token], 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
    # Erreur Mauvais Auth Token
    if @response["error"] == "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      redirect_to unauthorized_path
    # erreur de validation
    elsif @response["error"]
      raise
      @errors = @response["errors"]
      render :multiple_new
    else
      raise
      redirect_to account_path(account_id)
    end
  end
end
```

I have a corresponding method in my room_controller.rb that is responsible for creating rooms, beds for each rooms and slots for each beds. On the API I am using Pundit for authorization.

```
  def multiple_create
    i = 0
    start_date = Date.today
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      while i < params[:room_number].to_i
        @room = @hotel.rooms.build(room_params)
        authorize @room
        if @room.save
          (0...params[:bed_number].to_i).each do
            @bed = @room.beds.create!
            for a in 0...60
              @bed.slots.create!(available: true, date: start_date + a.days )
            end
          end
          i+=1
        else
          break
        end
      end
    end
    if i == params[:room_number]
      render json: {success: "All rooms and beds where successfully created"}
    else
      render json: {error: "There was a problem during room creation process. Please try again later"}
    end
  end
```

Everytime I try to post on this method I get :

```
Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError - Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError:
  pundit (1.0.1) lib/pundit.rb:103:in `verify_authorized
```

It seems to me I am actually calling authorize @room before saving the new room during the loop. I have a method multiple_create in my `room_policy.rb`:

```
  def multiple_create?
    (user && record.hotel.account.admin == user) || (user && user.manager && (user.account == record.hotel.account))
  end
```

And in my API base_controller I have :

```
after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
```

Why am I getting this pundit error here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a very creative solution - however there is a much way simpler and better way to deal with inserting / updating multiple records.

```
class Hotel
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
end
```

[`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) means that you can create rooms with:

```
@hotel = Hotel.new(
  rooms_attributes: [
     { foo: 'bar' },
     { foo: 'baz' }
  ]
)

@hotel.save # will insert both the hotel and rooms
```

You would create a form like so:

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :rooms do |rf| %>
   <%= f.foo %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And handle it in your controller like so:

```
class HotelsController

  def update
    @hotel.update(hotel_params)
    respond_with(@hotel)
  end

  private 
    def hotel_params
      params.require(:hotel).permit(rooms_attributes: [ :foo ])
    end
end
```

You can nest it deeper with multiple `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields` for. But in general when you go more than one level down thats a serious code smell. Split it into multiple controllers instead.

Note that you don't really need a `create_multiple` or `update_multiple` action.

So back to the core of the question, how do I authenticate it? *Keep it simple stupid*.

```
def update
  authorize @hotel
  # ...
end
```

and handle it in your `HotelPolicy`.

```
def update?
  return false unless user
  record.account.admin == user || (user.manager && (user.account == record.account))
end
```

### Edit

Based on your description of what you want to do you could simply add a custom getter / setter on your Hotel model.

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms

  # custom getter for binding form inputs
  def number_of_rooms
    rooms.count
  end

  # custom setter which actually creates the associated records
  # this subtracts the existing number of rooms so that setting
  # hotel.number_of_rooms = 50 on an existing record with 20 rooms
  # will result in a total of 50 not 70.
  def number_of_rooms=(number)
    (number.to_i - number_of_rooms).times { rooms.new }
  end
end
```

When you create or update a record like so:

```
[14] pry(main)> h = Hotel.new(number_of_rooms: 3)
=> #<Hotel:0x007feeb6ee2b20 id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[15] pry(main)> h.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "hotels" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.723803"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.723803"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("hotel_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["hotel_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.726157"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.726157"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("hotel_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["hotel_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.728636"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.728636"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("hotel_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["hotel_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.730291"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-08 13:17:06.730291"]]
   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true
[16] pry(main)>
```

It will add build N number of associated rooms. You can then save the record normally.

You would add this to your normal hotel update / create action by simply adding a form input for `number_of_rooms`:

```
<%= form_for(@hotel) |f| %>
  <% # ... %>
  <%= f.label :number_of_rooms %>
  <%= f.number_field :number_of_rooms %>
<% end %>
```

This input will be in `params[:hotel][:number_of_rooms]`. You should add it to your strong parameters whitelist.

Note that however you won't be able to set attributes per room. Follow the recommendation above for authorization.

Comment: thanks @max. I don't understand why you say I don't need a multiple_create action. What I want to do in my form is ask the user for the number of rooms and the number of beds in each room he wants to create (that is ```params[:room_number]``` and ```params[:bed_number]```. ```bed_number```and ```room_number```are not bed attributes are room attributes, they are just a factor I use to know how many instances I need to create. With that in mind do you still think I dont need a ```multiple_create```action ?

Comment: Not really, you just need to do a patch request on the parent record. But you should definatly not be authorizing in the the loop - just check once if the user can update/create a record.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand how I can achieve my multiple creation action in the update method ? How should I use my params[:room_number] and params[:bed_number] ?